# Access other service's API

Tags: spring-boot

In our Angular + Spring boot application application, we have 2 Controllers (2 Services are internally referenced). In first controller, We are sending a File from UI and reading the content of the file , query an external application and retrieve a set of data and return only a sub-set of Data, for entering as recommendation for UI fields. why we are returning only sub-set of data received from the external application? Because, we need only those sub-set data for showing recommendations in UI.
Once the rest of the fields are filled, then, we call another controller to generate a report. But, for generation of files, the second service requires the rest of the data from external application, which is received by the first service. I understand that Autowiring the first service in the second service, will create new instance of the first service and I will not get the first service instance, which is used to query the external application. I also like to avoid calling the external application again to retrieve the same data again in the second service. My question is how to fetch the data received by the first service in the second service?

**For example:**
First controller (`ExternalApplicationController`), which delegates loading of loading/importing of data from files

```java
public class Department{
  
  private Metadata metadata; // contains data such as name, id, location, etc.,
  
  private Collection<Employee> employees; // the list of employees working in the department.
  
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/externalApp")
public class ExternalApplicationController{

@Autowired
private ExternalApplicationImportService importService;

  @PostMapping("/importDepartmentDataFromFiles")
  public Metadata importDepartmentDataFromFiles(@RequestParam("files") final MultipartFile[] files) {
    return this.importService.loadDepartmentDetails(FileUtils.getInstance().convertToFiles(files)).getMetadata();
  }
}
```

The first service (`ExternalApplicationImportService`), which delegates the request to the external application for loading of department data.

```java
@Service
public class ExternalApplicationImportService{
  
  private final ExternalApp app;
  
  public Department loadDepartmentDetails(File file){
    return app.loadDepartmentDetails(file);
  } 
}
```

The `Metadata` from the `ExternalApplicationController` is used to populated UI fields and after doing some operations (filling up some data), user requests to generate a report(which contains details from the employees of that department)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reportGenerator")
public class ReportController{
  
@Autowired
private ReportGenerationService generationService;  

  @PostMapping("/generateAnnualReports")    
  public void generateAnnualReports(){
    generationService.generateAnnualReports();
  }
  
}

@Service
public class ReportGenerationService{
  
  public void generateAnnualReports(){
      //here I need access to the data loaded in the ExternalApplicationImportService.
  }
}
```

So, I would like to access the data loaded in the `ExternalApplicationImportService` in the `ReportGenerationService`.

I also see that there would be more services created in the future and might need to access the data loaded in the `ExternalApplicationImportService`.

How can this be designed and achieved?

I feel that I'm missing something how to have a linking between these services, for a given user session.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: if the data that you want to store and share between services is a file or object you could use object stores like https://min.io/ and if it is just some data you could use redis.

Answer (score 1):

You speak about user session. Maybe you could inject the session of your user directly in your controllers and "play" with it?

Just adding HttpSession as parameter of your controllers' methods and spring will inject it for you. Then you just have to put your data in the session during the first WS call. And recover it from the session at the second WS call.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reportGenerator")
public class ReportController{

    @PostMapping("/generateAnnualReports")  
    public void generateAnnualReports(HttpSession session){
        generationService.generateAnnualReports();
    }
    
}
```

Alternatively for the second call you could use:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reportGenerator")
public class ReportController{

    @PostMapping("/generateAnnualReports")  
    public void generateAnnualReports(@SessionAttribute("<name of your session attribute>") Object yourdata){
        generationService.generateAnnualReports();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Hello @mohicane Yes I have tried, But, as jccampanero mentioned in the below answer, my understanding and assumption that 'new instance of bean is always created for service for each rest call.'.

Comment: @Paul-E No Paul, the approach suggested by mohicane is fine as well: Spring will give you the same session for all the same user interactions. Please, be aware that it is not a bean but a Java EE concept, based on the use of cookies, etc. In this case, Spring is just an intermediary between your servlet container and your controllers. Please, do not confuse sessions with session scoped beans or _common_ beans which, on the contrary, will be created as singleton (only one instance for the whole application) available while your application is running, always the same object with its state.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting from a wrong assumption:

> I understand that Autowiring the first service in the second service, will create new instance of the first service and I will not get the first service instance, which is used to query the external application.

That is not correct: [by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes), Spring will create your bean as *singleton*, a single bean definition to a single object instance for each Spring IoC container.

As a consequence, every bean in which you inject `ExternalApplicationImportService` will receive the same instance.

To solve your problem, you only need a place in where temporarily store the results of your external app calls.

You have several options for that:

- As you are receiving the same bean, you can preserve same state in instance fields of `ExternalApplicationImportService`.

```java
@Service
public class ExternalApplicationImportService{
    
  private final ExternalApp app;

  // Maintain state in instance fields
  private Department deparment;
    
  public Department loadDepartmentDetails(File file){
    if (department == null) {
      department = app.loadDepartmentDetails(file);
    }

    return department;
  }  
}
```

- Better, you can use some cache mechanism, the [Spring builtin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) is excellent, and return the cached result. You can choose the information that will be used as the key of the cached data, probably some attribute related to your user in this case.

```java
@Service
public class ExternalApplicationImportService{
    
  private final ExternalApp app;
  
  @Cacheable("department")
  public Department loadDepartmentDetails(File file){
    // will only be invoked if the file argument changes
    return app.loadDepartmentDetails(file);
  }  
}
```

- You can store the information returned from the external app in an intermediate information system like Redis, if available, or even in the application underlying database.
- As suggested by Mohicane, in the Web tier, you can use the http sessions to store the attributes you need to, directly as a result of the operations performed by your controllers, or even try using [Spring session scoped beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-session). For example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/externalApp")
public class ExternalApplicationController{

@Autowired
private ExternalApplicationImportService importService;

  @PostMapping("/importDepartmentDataFromFiles")
  public Metadata importDepartmentDataFromFiles(@RequestParam("files") final MultipartFile[] files, HttpSession session) {
    Deparment department = this.importService.loadDepartmentDetails(FileUtils.getInstance().convertToFiles(files));
    session.setAttribute("department", department);
    return deparment.getMetadata();
  }
}
```

And:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reportGenerator")
public class ReportController{
  
@Autowired
private ReportGenerationService generationService;  

  @PostMapping("/generateAnnualReports")    
  public void generateAnnualReports(HttpSession session){
    Department department = (Department)session.setAttribute("department");
    // Probably you need pass that information to you service
    // TODO Handle the case in which the information is not present in the session
    generationService.generateAnnualReports(department);
  }
  
}
```

In my opinion, the second of the proposed approaches is the best one but all are valid mechanisms to share your data between the two operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to store the HttpSession, but, for each rest call, I'm getting a new instance of HttpSession. I dont have any repository for storing the session and I'm using the MapSessionFactory for saving the sessions in the Map. But, I dont know how to set up and maintain the session and Communication between Angular UI app and Spring boot server instance,

Comment: You are welcome @Paul-E. It will depend on your app, whether it is stateless (without sessions, jwt token driven, for example) or stateful (with sessions). If you wanna or need to use session, you can use session scope beans as suggested. Or just store your information in your controller manually. I updated the answer with an example. Please, do not worry about session storage, the default provided by Spring I fine. Just, be sure that your application accept sessions. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation for you will be to revisit your design of classes and build a proper relationship between them. I feel you need to introduce the extra logic to manage your temporal data for report generation.

@Mohicane suggested to use `HTTP Session` in [above answer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache). It might be a possible solution, but it has an issue if your service needs to be distributed in the future (e.g. more than one runnable instance will serve your WEB app).

I strongly advise:

- creating a separate service to manage `Metadata` loading process, where you will have `load(key)` method
- you need to determine by yourself what is going to be a `key`
- both of your other services will utilize it
- this service with method `load(key)` can be marked by `@Cacheable` annotation
- configure your cache implementation. As a simple one you can use In-Memory, if a question becomes to scale your `back-end` app, you can easily switch it to Redis/DynamoDB or other data storages.

Referances:

- [Spring Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache)
- [Spring Caching Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)